# Beginner tutorial for elgg

Tags: elgg

Can any one suggest  good tutorials for studying elgg, for elgg beginners

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried here: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Tutorials/HelloWorld ?

Comment: thanks for your response, i will check  the document

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Elgg is quite easy, there are quite excelent tutorials on the network, you should always start with it [Main Documentation Page](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Main_Page) if you are looking for answers register on their [forums](http://community.elgg.org/) or better yet be part of their [mailing developer group](http://groups.google.com/group/elgg-development/?pli=1).

Still looking for specific topics? Then lots of blogs writes about elgg social framework, i regular visit

Spanish:

- [Como Crear una Red social Con Elgg](http://www.magarciaguerra.com/2010/04/como-crear-una-red-social-con-elgg/)
- [BlogBlog
  WhoIs(Mi Blog Personal)](http://blognecronet.blogspot.com/search/label/Elgg)

English:

- [Elgg
  Officials Blogs](http://blog.elgg.org/)
- [Elgg
  With Adsense](http://elggwithadsense.blogspot.com/)
- [JaneKnight
  Elgg blog](http://janeknight.typepad.com/elgg/)(This a quite nice Blog)

Answer (score 2):

I know its already late, but for the reference of any new comer:

There is some documentation at http://docs.elgg.org/ and the code reference at http://reference.elgg.org/ but the best way to learn is usually digging into the source code for Elgg itself, or for some of the better plugins out there.

If you have any doubts, register in the elgg community at http://community.elgg.org and ask there. The community members will help you.

There is also a book on Elgg 1.8 @ http://www.packtpub.com/elgg-18-social-networking/book

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Tutorials/Blog

Comment: thanks for your response, i will check the document

Answer (score 0):

Try reading

1. **Elgg 1.8 Social Networking** by Cash Costello; 
   or
2. **Elgg Social Networking** by Mayank Sharma

Answer (score 0):

You can get the development docs at http://docs.elgg.org/.

If you want to develop your own mod for elgg, I advise you to understand the callback mechanism firstly, it will help you a lot in the process of developping your own mod.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the full document of elgg  at [learn.elgg](http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.11/)